# Hiding element with max-width:0?

Tags: html, css, sass

There is one **li** element which I want to hide such that later I can apply special transition effect of expanding out. However, I still can't wrap my head around why **max-width:0** works in this case while **width:0** doesn't(the space occupied just disappears). I checked the property of **width**, **max-width**, **min-width** in dev tool and found out **min-width** is defaulting to **auto** greater than the 0 value of **width** and **max-width**. According to the spec on MDN, shouldn't **min-width:auto** wins?(which means the **max-width:0** shouldn't take any effect).
Here is the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-huang/pen/GRypRqR)

```
 &__logo {
    color: black;
    // width:0 doesn't work
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this flex property is messing with what you're attempting to do here

```
&__list-item {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
/* flex: 1; */   

//if you comment out the line above it should work 
fine i guess

justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It works. So here is my understanding on this(Not sure if I get it right): 
1. "max-width" overrides "flex" property
In this example, "width" won't work because it's overridden by "flex:1" and I forgot to take it into consideration.
To sum up, "flex:0" or "max-width:0" will work if either is set on flex item for hiding it

Comment: Glad that i could be of help, if you could upvote it would be nice. :)